# What's the best way to structure a Users table in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to build a Users table and get my head around how to model data in DynamoDB.

I have two basic access patterns to start with.

1. Get a user by id.
2. Get a user by email.

But I want to keep the table flexible so that later on I can store alternative login methods for a user and access those later.

Does the table below make sense?

It allows me to a `getItem` on the main table by user id `pk: user#123, sk: USER` and `getItem` on the gsi by email `pk: USER, sk: email#joe@gmail.com`.

I'm concerned that the gsi won't be able to effectively partition the data.

```
| pk       | sk_gsi1pk | gsi1sk                |
| -------- | --------- | --------------------- |
| user#123 | USER      | email#joe@gmail.com   |
| user#456 | USER      | email#sarah@gmail.com |
| user#789 | USER      | email#bob@gmail.com   |
```

Comment: USER would be a very bad GSI PK. You'd be creating a hot key immediately. Now, if the base table sk was user#email#joe@gmail.com, that'd be unique enough as the PK of the GSI and your app would be able to piece that together.

Comment: If I wanted to get a user by ID, I would have to do a query for pk: user#123 and sk:beginsWith:user#email#. Is that going to be slower than a getItem?

Comment: @alexedwardjones  GetItem will be your fastest operation, with query being slower by *maybe* a few milliseconds.  If that's meaningful in your application, consider performing the query with a limit of 1 (return only 1 response).  The latency of GetItem vs Query with limit=1 will be equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

A couple things here.

1. You can't do a `getItem` on a GSI. You can query it, but it does not guarantee uniqueness like the table's partition and sort do.
2. What you're doing there is reasonable. I question whether you need to include `email#` in front of the email address. If they are using a different form of login it wouldn't be the same anyway (e.g. joe@gmail.com != joe). It's also not clear that you need the sort key on the table, unless you expect to store other records for the user, using the same partition key value.